# Why Does Stryker Fail To Run For This TypeScript Express Project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mutation-testing, stryker

I have a [public repo here](https://github.com/JimLynchCodes/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example) that is a simple ExpressJS NodeJs project in TypeScript which uses Jest for unit tests.

When I run `npx stryker run --fileLogLevel trace --logLevel debug` though I get this output and error:

```
16:23:03 (41154) INFO ConfigReader Using stryker.conf.js in the current working directory.
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG ConfigReader Loading config stryker.conf.js
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG PluginLoader Loading stryker-* from /Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG PluginLoader Expression stryker-* not resulted in plugins to load
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG PluginLoader Loading plugins /Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/reporters/index.js
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG PluginLoader Loading plugins /Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/mutators/index.js
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG BroadcastReporter Broadcasting to reporters ["clear-text","progress"]
16:23:03 (41154) INFO InputFileResolver Found 3 of 11 file(s) to be mutated.
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG InputFileResolver All input files: [
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/jest.config.js",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/package-lock.json",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/package.json",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/src/app.ts",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/src/sum.test.ts",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/src/sum.ts",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/stryker.conf.js",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/tsconfig.json",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/.gitignore",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/LICENSE",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/README.md"
]
16:23:03 (41154) DEBUG InputFileResolver Files to mutate: [
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/src/app.ts",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/src/sum.test.ts",
  "/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/src/sum.ts"
]
16:23:03 (41154) WARN TestFrameworkOrchestrator Missing config settings `testFramework`. Set `coverageAnalysis` option explicitly to "off" to ignore this warning.
16:23:03 (41154) ERROR StrykerCli an error occurred Exception [Error]: Could not inject "InitialTestExecutor". Inner error: Could not inject "TranspilerFacade". Inner error: Cannot load Transpiler plugin "typescript". In fact, no Transpiler plugins were loaded. Did you forget to install it?
    at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:35:19)
    at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:95:22)
    at Stryker.<anonymous> (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/Stryker.js:75:30)
    at step (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:133:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:57)
    at fulfilled (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62) {
  innerError: Exception [Error]: Could not inject "TranspilerFacade". Inner error: Cannot load Transpiler plugin "typescript". In fact, no Transpiler plugins were loaded. Did you forget to install it?
      at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:35:19)
      at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:95:22)
      at ClassProvider.result (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:173:21)
      at ClassProvider.resolveInternal (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:131:36)
      at /Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:56:33
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at ClassProvider.resolveParametersToInject (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:49:23)
      at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:31:31)
      at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:95:22)
      at Stryker.<anonymous> (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/Stryker.js:75:30) {
    innerError: Error: Cannot load Transpiler plugin "typescript". In fact, no Transpiler plugins were loaded. Did you forget to install it?
        at PluginLoader.resolve (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/di/PluginLoader.js:40:19)
        at PluginCreator.create (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/di/PluginCreator.js:11:42)
        at /Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/transpiler/TranspilerFacade.js:17:103
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at new TranspilerFacade (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/stryker/src/transpiler/TranspilerFacade.js:17:14)
        at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:32:20)
        at ClassProvider.injectClass (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:95:22)
        at ClassProvider.result (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:173:21)
        at ClassProvider.resolveInternal (/Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:131:36)
        at /Users/jim/Git-Projects/mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example/node_modules/typed-inject/src/InjectorImpl.js:56:33
  }
}
```

I thought I should have all the necessary things installed already since I followed all the documentation and have these three striker dev dependencies installed in my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mtdd-typescript-nodejs-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "from the live stream!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "mtdd": "stryker run"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@stryker-mutator/typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "stryker": "^0.35.1",
    "stryker-api": "^0.24.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Anyone see how I can get stryker running properly in this project? Thanks!

PS. I am using node v18.17.0

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`stryker`](https://npmjs.com/package/stryker) package which is deprecated. You want the [`@stryker-mutator/core`](https://npmjs.com/package/@stryker-mutator/core) package instead. For the easiest setup I'd recommend removing the `stryker` and `stryker-api` packages, running `npm install`, and `npx stryker init`. See the [quickstart](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-js/getting-started/)